# How to get my Ebay listings including EAN ( GTIN/ISBN)

Tags: ebay-api

I struggle with the Ebay-APIs in trying to get the information I need about my own products. I would like to use the EAN-codes in my offers to sync the stock quantity with another shop system. (each EAN is unique in my offers)

Up to now I didnt manage to get this information:

- Trading API -> GetMyeBaySellingRequest doesn´t include EAN, even when using DetailLevel=ReturnAll
- Neither does Large Merchant Services -> ActiveInventoryReport

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

**If** you are using the EAN as your unique way to identify your items, then you could just list the items in the first place with the EAN in the SKU field (Note: SKU is synonymous with the "custom label" that you see on the front-end of eBay).

**Depending** on how you stored the EAN in the listing when it was uploaded you might be able to pull the EAN using [GetSellerList](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetSellerList.html#Response.ItemArray.Item.ReturnPolicy), and for some reason EAN is buried within the return policy (use ItemReturnDescription or ReturnAll):

`<ReturnPolicy> ReturnPolicyType
        <Description> string </Description>
        <EAN> string </EAN>
        <Refund> string </Refund>
        <RefundOption> token </RefundOption>
        <RestockingFeeValue> token </RestockingFeeValue>
        <RestockingFeeValueOption> token </RestockingFeeValueOption>
        <ReturnsAccepted> string </ReturnsAccepted>
        <ReturnsAcceptedOption> token </ReturnsAcceptedOption>
        <ReturnsWithin> string </ReturnsWithin>
        <ReturnsWithinOption> token </ReturnsWithinOption>
        <ShippingCostPaidBy> string </ShippingCostPaidBy>
        <ShippingCostPaidByOption> token </ShippingCostPaidByOption>
        <WarrantyDuration> string </WarrantyDuration>
        <WarrantyDurationOption> token </WarrantyDurationOption>
        <WarrantyOffered> string </WarrantyOffered>
        <WarrantyOfferedOption> token </WarrantyOfferedOption>
        <WarrantyType> string </WarrantyType>
        <WarrantyTypeOption> token </WarrantyTypeOption>
      </ReturnPolicy>`

**Alternatively**, if you are using item specifics to display the EAN then you may need to pass a list of all of your items (which you can get using GetMyeBaySelling in conjunction with ActiveList) into the shopping API using [GetMultipleItems](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetMultipleItems.html) to extract all of the item specifics in sets of 20's.

Comment: Thank you, Isaac. You did a very good job in explaining the alternatives!

Comment: Do you still searching for a solution?