# eBay API getSellerList call not returning UPC, EAN and how to get selling limits

Tags: python, ebay-api

I have two questions about ebay api:
1)  I am trying to get my store selling limits, Which call should I do to get it. For now the only way I found is create the `GetMyEbaySelling` api call with `SellingSummary:True`. But it return me only the quantity remaining and amount remaining but not the total amount limit, and total quantity limit.

2) I am doing `getSellerList` api call with `DetailLevel: ReturnAll` but I don't got the Ean, mpn UPC fields (Even not the `VariationProductListingDetails`)

Thanks in advance

Lior

Comment: For #2 look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35291517/how-to-get-my-ebay-listings-including-ean-gtin-isbn

Comment: I don't have it there..